# How to prevent rxjs pipe operator from looping through two user/system defined inputs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using Angular with Ngrx. I currently have a DataSource that loads data from the store, but if not found, a service call will be made to the back end to fetch required data.

My problem is that whenever I pass a new argument to the load method inside the DataSource, It loops through the previous and the new values (ex. 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, .....)

So far with the rxjs `take(1)` operator, this stops the infinite loop but there are times where the previous data is the one being mapped and not the new ones.

I have tried searching online on how/why this happens but found none, or maybe I'm just using the wrong keywords.

This is the load method that I have mentioned above

```
 load(departmentId: number) {
    this.store.pipe(
      take(50),
      select(selectDepartmentSignatories(departmentId)),
      tap((signatories: SignatoryListItem[]) => {
        if (!!signatories && signatories.length > 0) {
          //map signatory details
        } else {
          this.store.dispatch(DepartmentSignatoriesRequested({ payload: { departmentId } }));
        }
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }
```

EDIT: Added the action dispatch in the else statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the observable is getting subscribed on each load.
Instead use `Subject` for this.

```
loadDept$: Subject = new Subject<number>();

  ngOnInit() {
    const loadDeptSub$ = this.loadDept$.pipe(
      switchMap(deptId => {
        return this.store
          .pipe(
            select(selectDepartmentSignatories(departmentId)),
            map((signatories: SignatoryListItem[]) => {
              return {
                signatories, departmentId
              }
            }),
            take(1)
          );
      })

    );

    loadDeptSub$.subscribe(payload => {
      if (payload.signatories && payload.signatories.length) {
        //do something
      } else {
        this.store.dispatch(DepartmentSignatoriesRequested({ payload: { departmentId } }));
      }
    });
  }

  load(departmentId: number) {
    this.loadDept$.next(departmentId);
  }
```

Also, don't forget to unsubscribe, else you'll introduce a memory leak.

Comment: I tried it out and it works perfectly! The piece of code you introduced will help me in many ways as i continue to study angular and the rxjs pipe operator. The code I posted above is what I have learned so far from a course i saw online.

Comment: Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be dispatching a load action and the logic should be in an effect. Having your logic in a tap is not they way to do things.

Comment: Hello, edited my answer to include the action dispatch.

So if I am understanding correctly, logics in a tap is never a good idea? If so, where should I put my logic?

The else statement is requesting for the data from back end, and then in the effects it stores the data received to the store.

Comment: Dispatching an action in a tap is not the way to do things.